# For what values of $a$ does $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2−1}+\frac{a}{x^3−1}$ have a limit $x=1$?

Tags: limits

> Let $a\in \mathbb{R}$ be given, we define $f : \mathbb{R}∖ \lbrace −1,1\rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the following way:
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2−1}+\frac{a}{x^3−1}$$
>   Find all the values of $a$ such that $f$ has a (finite) limit at $x=1$.

This is my problem: I found that $a$ could be $-\frac{3}{2}$, but I don't know how to prove that $-\frac{3}{2}$ is the only answer.

Comment: You mean, limit  at $x=1$ right ?

Comment: Please learn to format your question in $\LaTeX$ from https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Partial fractions?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=y+1$ which makes 
$$f=\frac{1}{x^2−1}+\frac{a}{x^3−1}=\frac{1}{2y+y^2}+\frac{a}{y \left(3+3y+y^2 \right)}=\frac 1y \left(\frac{1}{2+y}+\frac{a}{3+3y+y^2 } \right)$$ and perform long division
$$\frac{1}{2+y}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y}{4}+\frac{y^2}{8}+O\left(y^3\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{3+3y+y^2 }=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{y}{3}+\frac{2 y^2}{9}+O\left(y^3\right)$$ This makes
$$f=\frac 1y \left(\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)
   y+\left(\frac{2 a}{9}+\frac{1}{8}\right) y^2+O\left(y^3\right)\right)$$ that is to say $$f=\frac{\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{2}}{y}-\left(\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac
   {2 a}{9}+\frac{1}{8}\right) y+O\left(y^2\right)$$ So, in order to have a finite limit when $y\to0$, then $\frac{a}{3}+\frac{1}{2}=0$ that is to say $a=-\frac 32$ which makes $$f=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{5 }{24}y+O\left(y^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the limit at $x=1$ as you state in the question and not at $x=0$ as you state in the title.

First note that

$$\frac{1}{x^2-1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{1}{x^3-1}=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{x+2}{x^2+x+1}\right).$$

So,

$$\lim_{x\to 1} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{1}{x-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{2(x+1)}+\frac{a(x+2)}{3(x^2+x+1)}\right).$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}+\frac{a}{x^3-1}=\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)}+\frac{a}{(x-1)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{a}{x^2+x+1}}{x-1}$$
It's a $\frac{c}{0}$ situation. It's limit is $sgn(c)*\infty$ if c is not zero, or it requires more work if it is. So it can be finite only if:
$$\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{a}{x^2+x+1}=0$$
Let's substitute $x=1$:
$$\frac{1}{1+1}+\frac{a}{1^2+1+1}=0$$
$$\frac{1}{2}+\frac{a}{3}=0$$
Which is only true for $a=\frac{-3}{2}$, so it can have limit at $x=1$ only if $a=\frac{-3}{2}$.